# Future that returns large data works on emulator but not physical device

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, future, flutter-futurebuilder

I have a page that returns a list of audio files on the host device and i want to use the details of these files to create a list of audio files but it doesn't work on physical device(keeps loading) except emulator.

Here is the code. It stops at the first if block.

I have tried using futurebuilder and i also used async await but nothing changes. it keeps loading and doesn't display the files even though it shows in the console that the files have been fetched.

```
class _RoughState extends State<Rough> {
   late  Future<List<PlaylistItem>> audioFiles;
   Future<List<PlaylistItem>> getFiles() {
     audioFiles =
      LocalFilesList().getListOfAudioFilesOnDevice();
     return audioFiles;
   }
   @override
  void initState() {
     super.initState();
     audioFiles = getFiles();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.black,),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(future: audioFiles, builder: (
            BuildContext context,
            AsyncSnapshot<List<PlaylistItem>> snapshot,
            ) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                Visibility(
                  visible: snapshot.hasData,
                  child: const Text(
                    "snapshot.data!.first.title",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 24),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            );
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Text('Error');
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListOfSongs(audioFiles: snapshot.data!);
            } else {
              return const Text('Empty data');
            }
          } else {
            return Text('State: ${snapshot.connectionState}');
          }
        },),
        // child: Column(
        //   mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        //   children: [
        //     ElevatedButton(
        //         child: const Text("Scan Songs"),
        //         onPressed: ()  {
        //           audioFiles =
        //                LocalFilesList().getListOfAudioFilesOnDevice();
        //           print(audioFiles);
        //
        //           if (audioFiles.isNotEmpty) {
        //               Navigator.push(
        //                 context,
        //                 MaterialPageRoute(
        //                   builder: (context) =>
        //                       ListOfSongs(audioFiles: audioFiles),
        //                 ),
        //               );
        //           } else {
        //             ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
        //               content:
        //                   Text("No songs detected. Try adding songs to device"),
        //             ));
        //           }
        //         }),
        //   ],
        // ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: 81 files but it works when its about 1 to 3 files